# After set icon virus trouble

Tags: winapi, icons, antivirus

I have a question about setting icons to PE. I wrote 2 PE files, one is a target - it's empty Win32 Aplication and secont is Setter, setter do following tasks. It open ico file, do BeginUpdateResource, UpdateResource for each picture in ico, create GroupIconBuffer, and UpdateResource with this GroupIconBuffer and RT_GROUP_ICON as Parameter, and then EndUpdateResource. After this, icon set complite. BUT, AVG antivirus detect this file as a virus, Luhia.Fiha.a. Why???

Comment: There are a number of reasons, why anti virus software triggers an alarm: An application uses suspicious patterns (like modifying a PE image), the resulting image contains a byte sequence, that happens to match a known virus signature, the resource update was done with arguments, that turn the image into an exploit on access, or one of the Icons does contain a known exploit. We don't know, what it is. Since you have a repro, contact AVG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank's to all.
It is AVG specified behavior. This behavior fixes with deletion of 4px ico's from binary file.

Answer (score 0):

And VG is right. It is a "virus", because it modifies a binary executable...

Any non developer program that modifies a binary with executable should be treated as a virus.

Also all executable binaries should have a signature, such a program that modifies the exe must destroy the signature. Also under UAC you will never have write acceds to an executable in the program files folder or windows folder.

Comment: There is nothing intrinsically executable about PE files. PE specifies a container format, and many different file types use it: Executable images, DLLs, resource-only DLLs, object files, .winmd files, and so on. Modifying a resource-only DLL doesn't modify anything executable, for example.

Comment: Because resources are tightly bound to the xecutable (just think about a text with a format mask), changing the resource may change the behaviour of an EXE or DLL in a drastic way. And it will destroy the signature if one exists.

Comment: 6 AntiVirus don't detect this file and method. Only ANG Detect it. VIsualStudio, i think, do the same when set icon.

Comment: But VS is signed. May be there are several grades of "viruses", sign your program, it may not be detected as a virus. I use Eset and Symantec. Depending on the settings both program react very nervous or patient about such a change. Again: From my point of view it is wrong to do something like this. And our anti virus software are configured to be very sensitiv...

Comment: The fact, that resources are used by executable code, doesn't make a resource-only DLL all of a sudden *executable*. Your answer assumes a PE image that contains executable code, and your first comment assumes string table resources. Neither assumption is backed by the question as asked.

Comment: this action is documented at microsoft web site, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648004(v=vs.85).aspx
And i think i do correct things with correct files

Comment: I don't think so. This description discusses things that can be handled easier and with less conflicting methods. The existance of a function don't make its usage correct. Modifying a binary since UAC isn't a good way. Otherwise ask AVG for a different behaviour. But even than, other customers will run into similar problems with other virus software..